# Can i append some country and city code in mongodb unique object id?

Tags: mongodb, objectid, database, nosql

My question I am building database in Mongodb but problem is I have two field one is country and city, I want to query result mongodb like below

```
db.database.find({country:country_code,city:city_code})
```

As per my perception. It backend-side mongodb machine will perform operation like it will find first country_code records result will filter again with city_code,

In-stand of that I want to reduce time so I found one solution I do not know actually how Mongodb machine work, should I append country and city code in unique id so It become flexible solution ?

Something like this

```
db.database.find({A: {$regex: '/^*({country_code}{citycode})*$/''}})
```

I am new in mongodb, so please help me for best performance.

Thanks in advance,

Ronak Amlani

Comment: for best read performance, you need to create a compound index on field country, and city. `db.collection.createIndex({ country: 1, city: 1 })`. for more details, i suggest you go read through this https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/indexes/

Comment: Have you tried this query? Like 100k times and compared it to the first query? What where your results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an index on your fields.

```
db.<your collection>.createIndex({ country: 1, city: 1 })
```

Your regex solution is going to do very little in the way of performance and even worse probably make your database a maintenance nightmare later on.